# cd command doesn't work inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to get datetime and make a directory named as such, then `cd` to this directory.

This is my bash script:

```
t=$(date +%F-%H%M%S) 
mkdir $t
cd $t
```

but it doesn't work fully.

It creates a directory, but the `cd` command doesn't work.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of command prompt]

Comment: What does it mean "it's not working"? It perfectly works. If you want any help then describe how it actually behaves. "It's not working" is a nonsense.

Comment: the last line "cd" command is not work, before run this script is in home folder "~", and run this script also in home folder.

Comment: Again. It's working perfectly fine. Unless you describe how it really behaves (error messages etc.), nobody can help you. As I wrote "it's not working" is a bullsh*t.

Comment: OK, so now execute it `source test.sh` and you'll find out that it actually works. Check the Jeff's answer to find out why it behaves how it behaves.

Comment: Yes like  @ Dawid Ferenczy  said , it works prefectly... try this from the terminal : set -x ; t=$(date +%F-%H%M%S) ; mkdir -p $t && cd $t && pwd

Comment: Unless you use the `.` (dot) or `source` command on the script, the change of directory occurs in a sub-shell that exits immediately.  The parent shell is unaffected, but the `cd` _does_ work.  This is a duplicate of probably a number of similar questions — the difficulty, as ever, will be finding a good duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

you're running a script with a subshell.

the problem with running `cd` inside a script is that it creates a subshell starting from that directory.  when the script ends, so does your subshell, and you're back where you started when you ran the script. so it goes like this:

1. start script
2. subshell is created
3. create directory
4. change to directory
5. end script
6. end subshell
7. back to starting point

you can prove that `cd` works in the script and that you're inside that directory while executing your script by leaving a mark.

```
t=$(date +%F-%H%M%S) 
mkdir $t
cd $t
echo "I'm here" > inside.txt
```

now when the script ends, you'll be back where you started the script. but if you `cd` to the directory, and run `ls`, then you'll see the file you made.

---

as @Dawid Ferenczy points out, you can actually `source` this script into your current shell instead of running a subshell, such as:

```
source test.sh
```

Comment: It depends on how you execute the script. If you `source` it, it'll use the current shell and after the script finishes you'll be in the newly created directory.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy look at the OP's screen shot, they are running it with `sh`

Comment: You actually finished asking the question and answered it.  But you should use double quotes.  Hes testing shell scripts as root, can't be too careful.